# Indicates if an URL is tight to current controller in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

assume you are in Twig template and want to indicate if you are on a controller with any action.

The simple process you can check a single route is

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'app_user_list' %}
   // code...
{% endif %}
```

But I need something with a wildcard to determine if the action is under current controller like 'app_user_*' to match also 'app_user_add' or 'app_user_delete'. It is nonsence to if-else all possible routes.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html#slice) Twig filter, from the doc:

> The slice filter works as the array_slice PHP function for arrays and
>   mb_substr **for strings with a fallback to substr**.

So you can archive as example of matching a group of routing with the prefix of `app_user_` (app_user_add, app_user_delete, etc):

```
 {% if app.request.attributes.get('_route')|slice(0,9) == 'app_user_' %}
   // code...
 {% endif %}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would say this is a workatround instead of proper function in Symfony. I am worried there is not any official function for that even this is real life need.